# Create custom objects from CSV rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, object, cycle

I have the following CSV file:

```
id;area;zz;nc
1;35.66;2490.8;1
2;65.35;2414.93;1
3;79.05;2269.33;1
4;24.5;2807.68;1
5;19.31;2528.59;1
6;25.51;2596.44;1
```

where each rows represents a so called Cell object with its id, area, zz, cc.

Consequentially, I have created the following class:

```
class cells():
    #    
    # Initializer / Instance Attributes
    def __init__(self, idm, area,zz,nc):
        self.idm  = idm
        self.area = area
```

The idea is to create a number of object as the number of cells and to assign to them the attributes according to the data in the file.

The first idea that I have is to read the csv file as a DataFrame and after a list of objects to be populated in a cycle.

As far as I know, python is very inefficient with cycle and I would like to know if there is another way (smart one) to do that.

Thanks,
Diego

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you need them to be objects of specific class? Would you be alright with using `namedtuples` instead?

Comment: Also, your class should probably be named `Cell` instead of `cells`, since Python classes follow the _CapWords_ naming convention, and each object represents a single cell.

Comment: Do you find any of the current answers satisfactory, are you hoping for new ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you mean by cycle, but this will create a list of cell objects for each row that you have - given the format your data is in.

Pandas list comprehension over series is a reasonable option, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/7582537

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd 


class Cell():
    # Initializer / Instance Attributes
    def __init__(self, idm, area, zz, nc):
        self.idm  = idm
        self.area = area


def create_cells(row):
    newcell = Cell(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3])
    return newcell


file = pd.read_table("your_file.csv", sep=';')
zipp = zip(file['id'], file['area'], file['zz'], file['nc'])
cells = [create_cells(row) for row in zipp]

print(cells)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing that post, it was quite informative!

Comment: I hesitated for a while. I do agree that using a list comprehension or some other kind of plain Python iteration might make sense here, but I’m not a fan of using `pd.read_table()` and creating an entire function for what is just tuple unpacking in a constructor. In retrospect, I should have commented on those rather than just downvoting, sorry. For what it’s worth I have upvoted you know, since the solution is ultimately correct and generally well-written :)

Comment: I think that a key function is "zip". I have to understand it properly.

Comment: @diedro `zip()` is great, extremely useful function. It's a built-in function, and I think [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) do a good job of explaining it.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I also don't agree with this methodology. The only reason I suggested this method is because OP suggested the use of DataFrames and tagged `pandas`. I would definitely recommend your solution to read the file directly into the desired format. Also my answer was incorrect initially anyway, but I edited :)

Comment: @uMdRupert I just saw that the older version of your post included a disclaimer about the use of Pandas, you could have kept that, no? Although I imagine you had your reasons to get rid of it.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Yeah, I changed it after researching `pd.read_table` - as that is suitable for reading non-csv files as opposed to read_csv. But yes I agree, the premise still holds and there is no reason to use `pandas` here.

Answer (score 1):

uMdRupert shared a link to an interesting post in his answer, I would recommend checking it out!

---

I like his idea of using a list comprehension, so I wanted to share a similar method:

```py
import pandas as pd


class Cell:
    def __init__(self, idm, area, zz, nc):
        self.idm = idm
        self.area = area


cell_df = pd.read_csv('../resources/test_cell_data.csv', delimiter=';')
cell_df = cell_df.rename({'id': 'idm'}, axis='columns')

cell_objs_lst = [Cell(*curr_tuple._asdict()) for curr_tuple in cell_df.itertuples(index=False)]
```

---

Pandas might be overkill for this task, so here is a dead-simple method which uses the `csv` module:

```py
import csv


class Cell:
    def __init__(self, idm, area, zz, nc):
        self.idm = idm
        self.area = area


with open('../resources/test_cell_data.csv', newline='') as in_file:
    next(in_file)
    reader = csv.DictReader(in_file, fieldnames=['idm', 'area', 'zz', 'nc'], delimiter=';')
    cells_lst = [Cell(**curr_row) for curr_row in reader]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need pandas in this case. `pandas` is overkill if you only need to read a csv file.

either read it directly:

```
objects = []
next(f) # skip header row
with open('your_file', 'r') as f:
    for row in f:
        objects.append(cells(*row.strip().split(';')))
```

or using `csv` module.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your purpose of using object `Cells` for each row of `df`. However, I think you may achieve it with `df.agg` and keep every object in a series

```
class Cells():
    # Initializer / Instance Attributes
    def __init__(self, idm, area, zz, nc):
        self.idm  = idm
        self.area = area
        self.zz = zz
        self.nc = nc

s = df.agg(lambda x: Cells(*x), axis=1)
print(s)

Output:
0    <__main__.Cells object at 0x09FA38D0>
1    <__main__.Cells object at 0x09FA3510>
2    <__main__.Cells object at 0x09FA3870>
3    <__main__.Cells object at 0x09FA3AF0>
4    <__main__.Cells object at 0x09B27790>
5    <__main__.Cells object at 0x09B27770>
dtype: object
```

After that you may access each object from indexing of `s`

```
In [303]: s[0].__dict__
Out[303]: {'idm': 1.0, 'area': 35.66, 'zz': 2490.8, 'nc': 1.0}

In [304]: s[1].__dict__
Out[304]: {'idm': 2.0, 'area': 65.35, 'zz': 2414.93, 'nc': 1.0}
```

Comment: Where does `df` come from?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile: in the pandas world, `df` is always known as the working dataframe. OP says `The first idea that I have is to read the csv file as a DataFrame`, so I assume he already knew the way to read csv to dataframe. If he doesn't, a simple google would yield him the instruction to read_csv.

Comment: Right yes i’m familiar with the convention, I guess I was caught off guard because I only glanced at your mention of `df` in the beginning of your post. *facepalm*